# PartSim with 555 timer

Tags: partsim

I have used PartSim for discrete circuits but when I wanted to add a 555 timer chip there was nothing available in the list of components. I read about creating my own project models from spice text, which I tried but it makes no sense to me.

Is it possible to make circuits with chips like 555 etc.?

Comment: I have never used PartSim, but if it can accept SPICE models, it's hopefully not that difficult. If you can contemplate using LTspice, I can help you but probably someone with specific PartSim experience will chime in here.

Comment: :)  *Discreet*: not drawing much attention, tactful. *Discrete*: made from individual components.